# Internal behaviour of ++x as an lvalue in C++

Tags: c++, lvalue, pre-increment

I know in C++, you can have ++x as an lvalue and that it evaluates to x. But I ran the following code and am curious about what is going on behind the scenes.

```cpp
x = 10;
++x = x + 5;
```

In this case the final value of x is now 15. So does cpp not try to evaluate `++x` at all? Or does it do something like storing the result of `++x` in a temporary address and use the old value of x itself when evaluating `x+5` and then this value(15) just overwrites the temporary value(11)

There's no particular reason for running such a code and I know that. I am asking this purely out of curiosity

Comment: The short answer is "the compiler is written with the assumption that you won't write code like that", and so stuff breaks.

Comment: The long answer---the way that compilers deal with variables these days is much more complicated than just storing a value in a location. Once the compiler starts working on your code, it's no longer thinking about a single variable "x", but it's processing every change that happens to x as if it were a different variable. So you'll have `x1 = 10;` and then `x2` is the result of `++x`, and then `x3` is the result of `x + 5`. This is called "SSA". The compiler may also notice that `++x = x + 5` is "impossible", which may result in a "poison" value... which means it gets deleted from your code.

Comment: This code is equivalent to

    `x = 10; (x += 1) = x + 5;`

The expression `x += 1` normally (except if overloaded differently) returns a reference to the variable `x`. So the compiler calculates `x + 5 -> 15`, then increases `x` by 1, then assigns `15` to `x`. (Probably the order is not strictly defined, so it would be Undefined Behaviour instead).

BTW The postfix operator (normally) returns a copy of x and therefore cannot be assigned that way.

Comment: @Sebastian: Your second guess is correct... the order is "unsequenced", according to the standard. You cannot say that `x + 5 -> 15` happens first, or `++x` happens first... it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian. The example made it really clear